# Fixed Navbar Working on Firefox, but not on Chrome

Tags: css, mobile, css-position, navbar, fixed

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Bobby__K/pen/eYZXQKo

I made a navbar with the encompassing `nav` given `position: fixed`.

```css
.main-nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 5%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
```

When I run this on Chrome, Firefox, and Firefox mobile, it works as intended; i.e. the navbar doesn't move and stays at the top. However, when I run it on Google Chrome mobile and scroll down, the navbar goes up a bit and then the fixed positioning seems to kick in. The problem here is that this cuts off a good 10% of my navbar.

Since this only happens when I preview Google Chrome's mobile view, I was wondering if this was just a visual bug shown in developer tools, instead of something that would happen once the website's live.

**Notes:**

- I've made it responsive using the input method and with CSS `:checked`. As such, I usually keep the checkbox to the side with overflow-x hidden. I've tested the project while having the checkbox on the screen, but the same problem happens, so that wasn't the problem.
- I've also tested this on Opera mobile view and Brave mobile view and the scrolling issue happens there too; so maybe this is something to do with how my code reacts to the Chrome Engine?
- I've **narrowed it down** to a weird interaction with my `@media` screen and query. Whenever I make a change, it fixes the problem. However, once I close developer tools and reopen it, the scrolling issue reappears.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use a stack snippet unless it actually adds something to the post (e.g. HTML, JS that logs something). Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you happen to have a codepen or something with the full html and css (and js if applicable).  I'm wondering if there's a conflicting style outside of .main-nav that's causing this.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://codepen.io/Bobby__K/pen/eYZXQKo

This only happens when I use the tablet button in dev tools. It doesn't happen when I just resize the window.

Comment: Looks totally fine to me.  I'm on macos, chrome version 84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit). 
I go into codepen, hit the responsive device button, then choose their ipad or iphone 5, and then scroll.  The navbar doesn't move at all for me.

Comment: I see, thanks for checking, I really appreciate it!

I'm just going to assume it's just a visual issue for myself. As long as it doesn't effect the end product, it should be all fine.

Comment: Sure thing!  Good luck!